# "Link is Answer" vs. "Link is Reference"

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I reviewing some cases on First Posts and get the following one: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10425701

The questioner post a link with the reference of his following little explanation. The explanation is not the best but in my opinion it is possible to solve the problem. I pressed the button "No action needed" but failed the audit because the following reason:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Where is the border between "The link is the Answer" and "The link is the Reference"?

I want to help to make stackoverflow better, but this case confuses me.

Comment: Remove the link.  Does the remaining text answer the question?  If so, then the link is a reference.  If not, then it is a link only answer.

Comment: if i remove the link the answer can solve the problem - the questioner copied the answer from here: http://getuikit.com/docs/slideshow.html#fullscreen and added the link as reference - in my opinion / what do you think about this?

Comment: I think that he should have also put the markup code in his answer. Showing how to do something is always better than just saying to do it

Comment: yes thats right, the explanation is not the best but enough to solve the problem. With this answer i know to add this class to get the solution (maybe). I would post the same answer but with more formatting and the example.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Post a good github library for solving the problem and give a brief description of how it works. Delete the link and the remaining answer **WILL NOT** solve the problem. And why does this question has so many close votes? I believe this question is very much relevant.

Comment: The question marked as duplicate doesn't have any answer that addresses the particular issue that is asked in question. Voting for reopening.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT in a broad sense, it can solve the problem.  It will give you the name of the github library, so someone can go find it.  But that is also a rough guideline, not an absolute rule.  There will always be exceptions.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT This is an XY-problem amd the duplicate addresses the Y problem.  "why did I fail this audit".  The OP only thinks his problem is the link only answer.  He failed because he failed to understand this was a bad post to begin with (which is complete separate from the link issue).

Comment: @HarikrishnanT - thats right but you can read my question at title. I know the post was not the best and i made a mistake to press the button. But in my opinion it was not because "The link is the answer"!

Comment: I don't believe so. The answer mentioned in this question had a link. Just providing the name of the library may not be helpful at all. In that particular case, that library may seem helpful and the user actually pointed to the library and gave a quick referance. So it was **OK** to keep the answer(Though I agree the answer needed some formatting).

Comment: And I believe the question in the context need to be closed. It is too broad.

Comment: You should take a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the comment that says the answer you reviewed was a link-only answer (but it was an auto-comment from the review queue, and probably part of the reason the answer was an audit to begin with).  The traditional test to determine whether the post is a link only answer is to strip the link out - does the remaining text still answer the question?

In this case, without the link, the answer is:

> Fullscreen slideshow
>
> To create a fullscreen slideshow that stretches to fill the entire viewport, just add the .uk-slideshow-fullscreen class.

That does appear to be an answer, so it is, by definition, not a link only answer.

That being said, the answer is terrible.  As you pointed out, he simply just copy and pasted the first useful line (and associated heading) from the link and put it down as his own answer.  Even though, it is linked, he is not directly attributing the text to anyone, hence, it could be considered plagiarism.

Similarly, he provides a only a vague idea of what to do.  There is no additional explanation, no code, nothing, just ".uk-slideshow-fullscreen class".

So your "No action needed" review was wrong.  You could have downvoted, you could have commented to ask him to expand the answer, you could have flagged it for plagarism, or if you were feeling particularly generous and felt the answer had potential, you could have tried to edit it to fix the problems.  Had you tried any of those, you would have passed the review audit.

Comment: ok thx, it was my fault to not edit the answer for more quality but the reason was cofusing. now i wait 7 days to do it better next time :)